# Enable BCMON from another app

Tags: java, android, wifi, packet-sniffers

I'm creating an app that sniff all the packets from wifi networks (project for college) using android studio. the app should first enable monitor mode in the device through enabling bcmon, then run airodump. Sniff packets, stop airodump and disable bcmonwhich will disable monitor mode. then the app will display the packets in a list.

I created 2 fab buttons one is green and one is red. When I press the green button it should enable bcmon and run airodumb, and the red one should stop airodump and disable bcmon.

The problem is when I press the green button is shows that bcmon is enabled etc., but the wifi is not turning off. When I press the red button, it turns off the wifi for few seconds then stops airodump and disable bcmon then turn wifi on again. Which is wrong.

This is my line of code to enable bcmon on the background thread:

```
Shell.SU.run(new String("/data/data/com.nadya.sniffingwifi/tools/enable_bcmon"));
```

And this is how it is called from mainActivity:

```
new backgroundThread().setContext(v1.getContext()).execute(new String[]{"enable_bcmon"});
Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), "Monitor Mode Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a shell script (with proper path setting)  like this one ?

```
#! /system/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs
export LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs/libfake_driver.so
/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/tools/enable_bcmon
```